# how are the "varying" values of a triangle calculated?

Tags: webgl

The title of my question is not clear, I failed to make it short and precise.
In the code below I pass attributes into the fragment shader.
I pass 6 attributes: I understood that these attributes are used at each vertex of the 2 drawn triangles.
BUT I pass these attributes in the fragment (varying).

How are the values between the vertices calculated?

*In the example I make a readpixel, I copy pasted the console log of this readpixel and I formatted it*

```js
"use strict";
    
   
let vertex = `
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute float a_number;
varying float v_number;
void main() {
  v_number = a_number;
  gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
}
`;
let fragment = `
precision highp float;
varying float v_number;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor=vec4(v_number,0,0,0);
}
`;

var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
canvas.width = 5;
canvas.height = 5;
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,5,5,0,gl.RGBA,gl.FLOAT,null);
      
let program = gl.createProgram();
const vertexShader=gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
const fragmentShader=gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertex);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragment);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

let numberBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,numberBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([1,2,3,4,5,6]),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([
-1, -1,
-1, +1,
+1, -1,
+1, -1,
-1, +1,
+1, +1,
]),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.useProgram(program);
let numberLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_number");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(numberLoc);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,numberBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(numberLoc,1,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);

let positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc,2,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);


gl.viewport(0, 0, 5, 5);

var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
let pixels = new Float32Array(5 * 5 * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 5, 5, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, pixels);
console.log(pixels);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<pre>
4.9  5.1  5.3  5.5  5.7
1.9  4.7  4.9  5.1  5.3
1.7  2.1  4.5  4.7  4.9
1.5  1.9  2.3  4.3  4.5 
1.3  1.7  2.1  2.5  4.1

</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're linearly interpolated:
`v1 * (1-s) + v2 * s`
however the fragment shader is sampling at the *center* point of fragments, not the corners, hence when you have two pixels as output, and your numerical range is 0 - 1, the left pixel has `.25` and the right pixel `.75`, if you had three pixels their left "intra pixel corners" would be at `0`,`.33`,`.66` and their right intra pixel corners would be at `.33`,`.66`,`1` so the numbers ending up in the output buffer would be the center between the two corners: `.166`,`.5`,`.833`.

```js
"use strict";
    
   
let vertex = `
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute float a_number;
varying float v_number;
void main() {
  v_number = a_number;
  gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
}
`;
let fragment = `
precision highp float;
varying float v_number;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor=vec4(v_number,0,0,0);
}
`;

var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
canvas.width = 2;
canvas.height = 2;
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,5,5,0,gl.RGBA,gl.FLOAT,null);
      
let program = gl.createProgram();
const vertexShader=gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
const fragmentShader=gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertex);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragment);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

let numberBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,numberBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([0,0,1,1,0,1]),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([
-1, -1,
-1, +1,
+1, -1,
+1, -1,
-1, +1,
+1, +1,
]),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.useProgram(program);
let numberLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_number");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(numberLoc);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,numberBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(numberLoc,1,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);

let positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc,2,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);

const vd = 2;
gl.viewport(0, 0, vd, vd);

var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
let pixels = new Float32Array(vd * vd * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, vd, vd, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, pixels);
console.log(pixels);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<pre>
0 1
0 1
</pre>
```

Comment: I understand the 1st part (the text) very well. In the example you modify the code, numberBuffer=[0,0,1,1,0,1], why?

Comment: For the sake of the example in my answer I adjusted the buffer so that the vertices on the right have the number 1 and the ones on the left 0.

Comment: where are the documents explaining all this ? (I think it's in the glsl specifications on the khronos site but I couldn't find it)

Comment: You can find it documented in [Chapter 14 of the OpenGL Spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)(Page 462), it's also mentioned in the [GLSL gl_FragCoord manpage](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml), the reason for this and also why it's called a *fragment* shader rather than a *pixel* shader is the concept of multisampling, a quick overview in that regard can be found in the [OpenGL Pipeline Newsletter Volume 3](https://www.opengl.org/pipeline/article/vol003_6/). After all though it's really a matter of rasterization, not API.